# Selenium ChromeDriver with AdBlock in incognito

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open ChromeDriver with extension AdBlock in incognito.

I try with

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.addArguments("--load-extension=...\\adblock");
```

This work if I open ChromeDriver without incognito, but in Incognito don't work. How can make AdBlock to work in incognito.

Comment: By default no extensions are loaded in incognito mode. I think the easiest would be to create a profile that allows adblock in incognito mode (you can enable it on the Extensions settings), and then use that profile in your code.

Comment: I done this before to take copy folder from extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Source: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium

Comment: With .crx I get an error: `Manifest file is missing or unreadable`